# How to tell mypy that I am explicitly testing for an incorrect type?

Tags: python, pytest, mypy

Consider the following toy example:

```
import pytest


def add(a: float) -> float:
    if not isinstance(a, float):
        raise ValueError("a must be of type float")
    return 10 + a


def test_add_wrong_type() -> None:
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as err:
        add("foo")  # mypy is complaining here

    assert str(err.value) == "a must be of type float"
```

`mypy` is complaining as follows:
Argument 1 to "add" has incompatible type "str"; expected "float"  [arg-type]

Well, `mypy` is correct. However, in that case I put in an incorrect type on purpose. How can I tell `mypy` to ignore this line`?

Put it differently, what is a pythonic way to test for an incorrect input type?

Comment: `# type: ignore[arg-type]` ?

Comment: I would argue that the value of mypy is that when properly integrated it eliminates the need to write these sort of tests altogether.

Comment: You're going to get a `ValueError` from `10 + a` anyway; I'm not sure it's worth the runtime cost just to change the message associated with it.

Comment: `cast(float, "foo")` would also work.

Comment: Actually `# type: ignore[arg-type]` is the only semantically correct thing to do here: you do not `cast`, you do not pretend that `"foo"` is a float, you are issuing a call which is invalid from typing perspective. The type checker warns you about this fact - however, you still want to go on, because it's a test and you're testing behaviour with unsafe calls. There's nothing wrong with `type: ignore` comments, python is not even typescript where all linters are crying as mad when you `@ts-ignore` until you disable this weird rule set.

Comment: Expanding on [@TeejayBruno's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438855/how-to-tell-mypy-that-i-am-explicitly-testing-for-an-incorrect-type#comment133106659_75438855), mypy is already verifying that all call sites use the right type, so your test is effectively a duplicate and doesn't need to exist.

Comment: @TeejayBruno @l0b0 I am not totally convinced that these kind of tests are unnecessary. Even if ``mypy`` issues warnings, the user can still call the function with an incorrect type.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. No amount of testing will _prevent_ a user from calling the function with an incorrect type. If it is your own codebase, your unit test is a less sophisticated redundancy for what `mypy` does. But even more importantly, your runtime check for `a` being a `float` inside `add` is redundant. The error message a user will get at runtime without your `isinstance` check, if he e.g. passes a `str`, is expressive enough. And static analysis tools combined with your type annotation will tell a user that _before_ he runs it. So ditch the runtime check **and** the test.

Answer (score 1):

The Python typing community has at least 2 ways of unit-testing type annotations. Note that `# type: ignore` and `typing.cast` are not *testing* them - they're ignoring them and overriding them, respectively.

Depending on your purpose, you'd want to go for one of the following:

- `stubtest`, which ships with mypy. This is extensively used by [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), but is more suited to check that any given type annotations in `.pyi` files match with the runtime implementation.
- [pytest-mypy-plugins](https://github.com/typeddjango/pytest-mypy-plugins), which sounds like what you should go for in your example. Taking an example from [`README.md`](https://github.com/typeddjango/pytest-mypy-plugins#1-inline-type-expectations), you'd probably want to write something like this:

  ```yaml
  # test_add.yml
  - case: test_add_wrong_type
    main: |
      from my_module import add

      add("")  # E: Argument 1 to "add" has incompatible type "str"; expected "float" [arg-type]
  ```

  (I haven't tested this - their documentation doesn't mention inline-testing errors. I took the `# E: ...` syntax from the examples in [`mypy/test-data/unit`](https://github.com/python/mypy/tree/master/test-data/unit)).

You can also make `mypy` a runtime dependency for your pytest test suite, in which case you probably don't need `pytest-mypy-plugins` - their test suite runs on their [own non-exposed pytest hooks](https://github.com/python/mypy/tree/master/mypy/test), which you can import directly in your [`conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_plugins.html#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins). Just write out examples like their [`check-*.test`](https://github.com/python/mypy/tree/master/test-data/unit) files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typing.cast` to assert that `"foo"` is a `float`.

```
from typing import cast


def test_add_wrong_type() -> None:
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as err:
        add(cast(float, "foo"))

    assert str(err.value) == "a must be of type float"
```

`cast` doesn't do type *conversions*; at runtime, it simply returns its second argument. Its purpose is to provide a standard way to assert a static type for a given value, independent of whatever type checker you might be using.

Comment: This is working, however, what I don't like is the fact that I have to call the function in a non-natural way. It just looks weird. Right now, I would go with @anthony sottile solution.

Comment: Is there any reason to use (quite unnatural) `cast` instead of `type: ignore`? It's intentionally invalid, why trying to convince `mypy` it isn't?

Comment: I assumed `typing.cast` was "more" standard, being defined and documented in the standard library rather than only being mentioned in passing in PEP 484.

Comment: `# type: ignore` wouldn't be able to handle a case where you only wanted to disable type checking on a single argument, though, would it?